# What should be the type expression of a 2D array?

Tags: compiler-construction, types

Type expression of an array with M elements of type T is

> array(1...M,T)

Then what it should be for an 2D array with M rows and N columns? Should it be a cartesian product of two arrays? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For M*N array, type expression will be

> **array(1...M,array(1...N, type))**

where M is the no of rows and N is the no of columns. Just consider a 2D array as an array of arrays.